# Cant keep sprite on screen, the ray cast selects all collision boaders and moves them, moving the whole back ground

Tags: c#, raycasting, unity-game-engine

I have a sprite that is moved by click and dragging and code works fine until I try to contain the sprite from leaving the scene. this issue is that I cannot work out how to drag one  game object and ignore rest of the scene.  tried using if statements and tags but getting cannot convert string to bool or other conversion errors.

Code below is attached to main camera

```
public GameObject gameObjectToDrag; // refer to Go that being dragged

public Vector3 Gocenter; // gameobject centre
public Vector3 touchPosition; // touch or click position
public Vector3 offSet; // vector between touchpoint/mouse click to the object centre
public Vector3 newGOCenter; // new center of object

RaycastHit hit; // store hit object information

public bool draggingmode = false; //   



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    //********************************
    // **Click to Drag****************
    //********************************
```

## if UNITY_EDITOR

```
    // first frame when user click left button

    /* if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
     {
         // convert mouse position to ray
         Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

         // if ray hit a collider (not 2dcollider)
         if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
         {
             gameObjectToDrag = hit.collider.gameObject;
             Gocenter = gameObjectToDrag.transform.position;
             touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
             offSet = touchPosition - Gocenter;
             draggingmode = true;
         }
     }

     // every frame when user hold left mouse
     if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
     {
         if (draggingmode)
         {
             touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
             newGOCenter = touchPosition - offSet;
             gameObjectToDrag.transform.position = new Vector3(newGOCenter.x, newGOCenter.y, newGOCenter.z);
         }
     }
     */

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit2D hit2d = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);



        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {

            gameObjectToDrag = hit.collider.gameObject;
            Gocenter = gameObjectToDrag.transform.position;
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            offSet = touchPosition - Gocenter;
            draggingmode = true;

        }


        if (hit2d )
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit something: " + hit2d.transform.tag);
            gameObjectToDrag = hit2d.collider.gameObject;
            Gocenter = gameObjectToDrag.transform.position;
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            offSet = touchPosition - Gocenter;

            draggingmode = true;

        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (draggingmode)
            {


                    touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                    newGOCenter = touchPosition - offSet;
                    gameObjectToDrag.transform.position = new Vector3(newGOCenter.x, newGOCenter.y, newGOCenter.z);

            }
        }


    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        draggingmode = false;
    }
```

## endif

Answer (score 0):

it was simple I used layers to ignore the ray cast.

sorry